# Random Start Location For Balls, avoiding Collisions

Tags: java, swing, random

I am aware there are some similar questions to this existing, however my code is slightly different and I feel it's almost finished I just need a slight tweak but I'm not sure exactly what.

My goal is to spawn the circle in the 900x600 canvas, without them colliding initially. The amount of balls is specified by the user up to a maximum of 100.

My method so far:

```
startCounter = 8;

balls = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    diameter = random.nextInt(30) + 10 + diameterRange; //generate diameter value for ball
    startCounter += diameter + 25; //stop balls from spawning on top of each other

    BouncingBall ball = makeBall(startCounter, diameter, i);
    if (Physics.Collision(ball, balls)
      || ball.getXPosition() > 850 || ball.getYPosition() > 550)
    {
        continue; //avoid starting collisions
    }

    balls.add(ball);
}
```

Currently this almost works perfectly, except it will just not create balls if they fail the if statement, resulting in fewer balls than the user specifies.

I tried adding i--; to the contents of the if statement, but this doesn't work and balls seem to spawn incorrectly in this case.

Thanks:)

Comment: It happens because i (the index) is still increasing, either increase amount or change it to while loop (better to change)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it, thanks for your help people:)

```
               startCounter = 8;
                balls = new ArrayList<>();

             while (balls.size()<amount){
                 int i = 0;

                    diameter = random.nextInt(30) + 10 + 
                diameterRange;//generate diameter value for ball

                    startCounter = random.nextInt(800) + 100;
                    startCounterY = random.nextInt(400) +100;
                    BouncingBall ball = makeBall(startCounter, 
                   startCounterY, diameter, i);
                    if (Physics.Collision(ball, balls)||ball.getXPosition()> 
                    850||ball.getYPosition()>550){

                        continue;
                    }

                    balls.add(ball);
                    i++;

                  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to while loop, i.e:

```
startCounter = 8;
balls = new ArrayList<>();
int goodBalls=0;
while (goodBalls<amount){
  diameter = random.nextInt(30) + 10 + diameterRange;//generate diameter value for ball
  startCounter += diameter + 25;//stop balls from spawning on top of eachother
  BouncingBall ball = makeBall(startCounter, diameter, i);
  if !(Physics.Collision(ball, balls)||ball.getXPosition()>850||ball.getYPosition()>550){//avoid starting collisions
    balls.add(ball);
    goodBalls++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Poor formatting in the question is no excuse for poor formatting in your answer.

Comment: @EdTaylor I've corrected the initiation, can you accept the answer if it helped?

Answer (score 1):

For loops have the amount of loops determined before the first loop. A better approach would be to replace `for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)` with `while i < amount' and only increasing the i count if the condition is fulfilled (since while loops validate against the condition at the start of every loop via memory location.

The code should look like this
`startCounter = 8;
                balls = new ArrayList<>();

```
            while (i < amount) {
                diameter = random.nextInt(30) + 10 + diameterRange;//generate diameter value for ball
                startCounter += diameter + 25;//stop balls from spawning on top of eachother
                BouncingBall ball = makeBall(startCounter, diameter, i);
                if (Physics.Collision(ball, balls)||ball.getXPosition()> 850||ball.getYPosition()>550){//avoid starting collisions

                    continue;
                }

                balls.add(ball);
                i+=1;
            }
```

`

Comment: this method causes major bugs, the balls just get stuck now:S